# Spamass-Milter Network Issue

Tags: spamassasin

Spamass-milter man says the following about -i network flag: "Ignores messages if the originating IP is in the network(s) listed. The message will be passed through without calling SpamAssassin at all. Networks is a comma-separated list, where each element can be either an IP address (nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn), a CIDR network (nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn/nn), or a network/netmask pair (nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn/nnn.nnn.nnn.nnn)."

Now when I set it like this in /etc/default/spamass-milter,

```
OPTIONS="-u spamass-milter -i 127.0.0.1,123.456.78.990"
OPTIONS="-r 7.0"
```

It only applies my second option to reject emails that have their spam score higher than 7. However, when I send an email from my IP address 123.456.78.990 that has a score of 8 the email is not whitelisted in accordance with my -i flag set earlier, but rejected instead. How do I whitelist my IP address in spamass-milter? Would be really thankful for any pointers / suggestions.

It's all whitelisted in /etc/spamassassin/local.cf by domain names and by trusted network IP addresses as well.

Comment: Can you use several `OPTIONS=` lines in the file and have them all concatenated for you? Perhaps try putting all the options on one line.

Comment: Yes, it's all working fine in several "options=" lines as per numerous examples found online everywhere. The issue is that when it matches the score set (it's 7 in my case) it turns off / disables all the other options set either in one line or in 10 lines.